# Can't dpeloy React App (wih Vite) on Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, vite

I want to deploy a React App using Heroku,

When I go to the URL, I havea blank page and these logs in Heroku :

```
(!) Some chunks are larger than 500 kBs after minification. Consider:
- Using dynamic import() to code-split the application
- Use build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks to improve chunking: https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-manualchunks
- Adjust chunk size limit for this warning via build.chunkSizeWarningLimit.
```

I'm using Vite so I already tried solutions like the npm package `vite-plugin-chunk-split` but I still can't get my page

Answer (score 0):

You can Adjust chunk size limit   via `build.chunkSizeWarningLimit` in vite config  And you'll get rid of this warning . like this  :

```
export default defineConfig({
    ...,
    build: {
        chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1600
    }
});
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work, I still get a blank page with a 503 error when I get to my site :(

Comment: heroku returns this error Whenever your app experiences an error . you have to debug your app

Comment: ok it's hard because in dev mode everything works well, thank you